# given the position and velocity of an object how can I detect possible Collision?

Tags: collision-detection, ai, linear-algebra, collision-avoidance

I'm trying to detect Collision between autonomous moving objects and steer direction if collision is detected. so far I've been following a tutorial and I'm having a hard time to fully understand how it works especially the role of the dot product

```
foreach (GameObject t in targets) //get me all moving agents
{
 Vector3 relativePos;
 Agent targetAgent = t.GetComponent<Agent>(); //access properties like velocity 
 relativePos = t.transform.position - transform.position;
 Vector3 relativeVel = targetAgent.velocity - agent.velocity;
 float relativeSpeed = relativeVel.magnitude;
```

//can someone explain this part of code how did we calculate the time of collision?

```
 float timeToCollision = Vector3.Dot(relativePos, relativeVel);
 timeToCollision /= relativeSpeed * relativeSpeed * -1;
 float distance = relativePos.magnitude;
 float minSeparation = distance - relativeSpeed *
 timeToCollision;
```

Comment: If the code is from a tutorial, did you try to contact the author? If you did, then next you need to learn Vector Math. Go check wikipedia or a math tutorial on youtube. It'l explain dot products better than text.

Answer (score 1):

The dot product has two nice properties for collision avoidance. The dot product is closely related to the cosine of the angle between two vectors.

The dot product of a unit vector A and a second vector B of any non-zero length, the result is the length of vector A projected in the direction of vector B.

[image: dot product (taken from Wikipedia)]

So as you can see in the image; if the angle is greater than 90 degrees, the dot product will be negative. So, the dot product has to be a positive value or there will be no collision. Most likely in your code/tutorial the dot product is used to check if the objects are heading towards eachother (maybe based on a "viewcone" or something similar- for example a dot product of >0.5 equals a cone of 45 degrees). This is the first property: check if the objects are actually heading towards eachother by evaluating the angle between them.

Once decided a collision is likely based on the directions the objects, the next property comes into play:

The relPosition and relVelocity are is used to project the velocity vector onto the position vector:

```
float timeToCollision = Vector3.Dot(relativePos, relativeVel);
```

This line basically projects the Velocity (A in the image) onto the RelativePosition (vector pointing from the first agent to the 2nd agent).

Then the result is divided by the `relativeSpeed * relativeSpeed` (since the two objects both have their velocities turned into one relative speed value), to calculate the actual `timeToCollision`.

Note that this calculation *does not mean* the objects will collide! It merely calculates the time where the two objects are *the most close* to eachother during their trajectories (the variable name may be confusing you here!)

This is where these lines comes in:

```
float distance = relativePos.magnitude;
float minSeparation = distance - relativeSpeed * timeToCollision;
```

The minimal Separation is the distance between the two objects at the time of the closest approach. Remember `relativePos` is actually a vector from object A to B; the magnitude is the current distance. Shorten the distance by the distance travelled during the calculated timeframe `relativeSpeed * timeToCollision` and the result will be the minimal distance between the objects during the trajectories.

Now if the minimal distance is smaller than the sizes of the objects *they will collide* and the agent must take an evasive action.

The image is taken from the [Wikipedia page 'Dot product'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product).